# Salvar texto com quebras de linhas no BD

Tags: java, postgresql, java-8

Vejam abaixo um codigo java para salvar um retorno de comando SQL no PostgreSQL. O comando é o EXPLAIN ANALYZE. 
O problema é que ao salvar isso no banco de dados, ele perde as quebras de linha. Alguem saberia me ajudar a resolver isso, ou seja, para que ao fazer select e recuperar o texto ele venha com quebras de linhas e indentacoes.  O campo que preciso disso é o FULL_EXPLAIN abaixo, e o tipo de dados dele eh o "text" do postgresql.

---------------- JAVA CODE ---------------------

```
StringBuilder ConsultaExplain = new StringBuilder();
ConsultaExplain.append("EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)  ");
ConsultaExplain.append(SQLtxtQuery);

ResultSet result2 = BancoDeDados.getResultSet(ConsultaExplain.toString());

StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
str1.append("Execution plan...:");
SQLtxtQuery2 = SQLtxtQuery;
while (result2.next()) {
    SQLtxtQuery2 = result2.getString(1);
    str1.append(SQLtxtQuery2);
}
    String myString = str1.toString();
    String myNewStringNoQuotes = myString.replaceAll("'", "_");

StringBuilder exeSQLUpdateTabAcao = new StringBuilder();
exeSQLUpdateTabAcao.append(
"UPDATE TAB_CTRL_TEMPO SET OCORRENCIA_TEMPO= current_timestamp, FULL_EXPLAIN ='");
exeSQLUpdateTabAcao.append(myNewStringNoQuotes);
exeSQLUpdateTabAcao.append("' WHERE id = currval('tab_ctrl_tempo_id_seq')");
BancoDeDados.execStatement(exeSQLUpdateTabAcao.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Após alguns teste, eu irei responder minha própria pergunta:

A solucao foi inserir  System.getProperty("line.separator"); em cada iteracao do loop While, veja:

```
String variavel = System.getProperty("line.separator");
 SQLtxtQuery2 = SQLtxtQuery;
 while (result2.next()) {
    SQLtxtQuery2 = result2.getString(1);
    str1.append(SQLtxtQuery2);
    str1.append(variavel);
}
```